# Migrate WebApp from Tomcat to WebLogic

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, migration, weblogic

I need to migrate an existing java web application to Weblogic 12. 
Is there a tutorial that explains me step by step what I should do for a correct migration? 
What files should I change or add to do this?

I will appreciate your help

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

The question is a bit too broad to give you specific answers. But usually, it's easier this way than trying to make an application run with Tomcat which ran on an application server, because with your Tomcat application you most likely already have a WAR file containing all the stuff you need.

The problem you might have is that you bring libs that are already part of the application server (e.g. JPA or JSF). So you want to eliminate all the standard Java EE libs from your WAR file.

Besides that, you should only have to care for WebLogic specic configuration, like the datasource.